# Google cloud compute VM cannot change SSH port

Tags: centos, sshd, vps, google-cloud

I have some experience about linux admin, this issue never happened when I use AWS EC2 or other VPS.

After I create centos7 vm on google cloud compute engine, I changed only one line of sshd_config file(uncomment `Port 1234`),then create an iptabels rule to allow ingress port 1234.

And also selinux disabled. Then I restart sshd service and stuck there forever.
Connect to serial console, `sshd -t` no error shows, `/usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config` no error shows. Try `/usr/sbin/sshd -D` then sshd service start successfully and port 1234 can connected by PUTTY. Exit debug mode then sshd service cannot start again.

Is there any command I need to configure with google cloud console or something?

I'm kind of new to google cloud, so please help me with this strange issue.